# Internal css style definition

Tags: html, css

Having following code

```
  <head>
    <style>
        body { background-color:green; }
    </style>            
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
      alert(document.getElementsByTagName("BODY")[0].style.backgroundColor);
    </script>
  </body>
```

the alert shows nothing (no result, empty string).
When i move the style definition to a `body` tag (`<body style="background-color:green">`) it works as expected - returns "green" string. Why doesn't getting the internal style (inside a `style` tag) value work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `.style` property of an element shows the style that is set by the `style` attribute or directly assigned to the property of the element but not the computed style ([HTMLElement.style](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style)). To get that you have to use [Window.getComputedStyle()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)

```
var style = window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementsByTagName("BODY")[0]);
alert(style.backgroundColor)
```

Comment: so styles defined inside an _style_ tag is called "computed" an have it's own getComputedStyle method?

Comment: @RobertWade `style.background-color` would be a syntax error, as of that the access can be done by removing each `-` and chaning the character following the `-` to uppercase.

Comment: @Mulligun81 no the the style in the `<style>` tag are rules that are applied according to the selector. The final style is computed by applying the rules defined in the `<style>` tags, in the css files, and the values set in the `style` attribute and property, and thats the computed style. If you would change your code to `<body style="background-color:red;">`, then both `document.getElementsByTagName("BODY")[0].style.backgroundColor` and `window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementsByTagName("BODY")[0]).backgroundColor ` would be `red`. Because the final calcualted color is `red`.

Comment: ok but to get the value of _style_ tag defined values the only method is getComputedStyle?

Comment: @Mulligun81 you can look into all stylesheets using `document.styleSheets`, there was a function `getMatchedCSSRules` but this function is deprecated and I don't know right now if there is any replacement.

Answer (score 0):

As already answered by t.niese, [getComputedStyle()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) is the JavaScript method that should be used to get the CSS styles.

**What it does actually?**

Well, it grabs the style values after being rendered in the browser window, and you don't see a blank as returned by the `document.body.style.backgroundColor`.

We can make it a bit more robust and browser-friendly; `currentStyle` method comes in handy for older versions of IE and Opera.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    body {
      background-color: green;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    // getComputedStyle for modern browsers, currentStyle for IE
    var style = window.getComputedStyle ? getComputedStyle(document.body) : document.body.currentStyle;
    alert(style.backgroundColor);
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Note that the color value returned by the method here will be in RGB.